# What method should I use to convert an int to a String?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I know that `String.valueOf(int)` enables caching and often does not cause an extra object to be created, but does `("" + 1)` get some kind of compiler optimization?

Which one should be used?

**EDIT**: String.valueOf(int) does not enable caching, Integer.valueof(int) does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"" + 1` is a bad habit in my opinion and as far as I know it is not optimized in any way.

Do stick with `String.valueOf(int)`.

Comment: Well, I thought they optimised this already (can't confirm where I read this).

Answer (score 5):

No, `String.valueOf` doesn't perform any caching. However, it's more *readable* than `"" + 1` (which also doesn't perform any caching) because it says what you want to do.

`"" + 1` talks about string concatenation and an empty string, neither of which have anything to do with your aim - which is to get the value of an integer, as a `String`.

`String.valueOf` says exactly what you want to do, so use that.

Answer (score 0):

They are both equivalent and it is more a matter of personal taste.  Personally, I prefer String.valueOf(int).

Answer (score 0):

**Choose explicit conversions over implicit ones.**

`String.valueOf(int)` tells you exactly what it is doing.

Although, I always use `Integer.toString(int)` because I read this as the `toString` method for a primitive `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.valueOf(int)` is reasonable optimal for the application.

`""+i` may be more optimal for you and unless you have loads of time and a resource limited device, saving your time may be more valuable than saving a micro-second of CPU time.